# Pundit skip_authorization not working via direct before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have a test that looks like this

```
test 'should get new' do
  get new_organization_url
  assert_response :success
end
```

When I run this test I get an error

```
Error:
OrganizationsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError
```

In my `organizations_controller` I was using

```
before_action :skip_authorization, only: [:create, :new]
```

Something odd I've noticed, if I implement the `skip_authorization` as

```
before_action :skip_auth, only: [:create, :new]
  
def skip_auth
  skip_authorization
end
```

This test passes. What's the difference, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because my `organizations_controller` had a concern that was mixing in some logic and using `before_action :skip_authorization, only: [:index]`

To fix this issue I updated my application_controller to use

```
after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index
after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index
```

And also learned I can't use the same method in two different before_actions (the :only arrays are not merged)